# JavaScript For loop ignored

Tags: javascript

Im trying to make a little program in js that overturns the text you typed in. The code runs fine, but the for loop gets completely ignored, it doesnt do even one block of code from inside of it.

```
    document.getElementById("StartButtonText").addEventListener("click",function(){           
        var text_value = document.getElementById('TextValue').value;
        console.log(text_value);

        var text_length = text_value.length;
        console.log(text_length);

        var final_text;
        var order;

        for (order = 1; order >= text_length; order ++) {
            final_text[order] = text_value[text_length - order + 1];
             
            console.log('for loop log ',order); 

            final_text = final_text + final_text[poradie]; 
        }

        console.log('after loop log ',order); 

        document.getElementById("TextTurningResult").innerHTML =  final_text;

        console.log(final_text);              
    });
```

Any ideas why it doesnt run?

Comment: `order >= text_length` should be `order < text_length`, and `order` probably should start at 0. Also `final_text` should be initialized.

Comment: Change this `order >= text_length;` to `order < text_length`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop will run as long as `order` is greater or equals than `text_length`.

I guess you wanted to write:

```
for (order = 0; order < text_length; order ++) { ... }
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! i didnt quite understand how that argument in the for loop works.

Comment: You have to define the initial value, the condition to loop again, and the statement called every loop (usually incrementing the variable).
Please consider acceptin the answer and mark the topic as resolved if you're all okay :)

Answer (score 0):

You should change the condition in your for loop to

for(order = 1; order <= text_length; order++){
...
}

In your case, the condition is false at the first iteration only.